# how to make a setup of my application?

Tags: java, ubuntu, installation

I've created a standalone java application using Netbeans. The application works in ubuntu 10.04 environment. Now I want to create a setup for my application so that I can distribute it to others. Also the path variables need to be changed depending upon the system on which i is installed. Can anyone suggest me how do I do so?

Comment: Can you describe who you are distributing it to? What sort of path variables are you referring to?

Comment: I'd like to distribute it to other people who can install the app on their system and then give me feedback regarding it. Actually the variables I've used in the code of my app are dependent on the machine on which the app is installed. It requires's the system root directory and all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello you can make an installer for your application.

In the link below you will find a nice help about izpack installer.

http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?p=89

Link below contains a detailed pdf to make installer with izpack.

http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?attachment_id=112

cheers

Imran tariq

Answer (score 0):

Try Flexera's **Install Anywhere**. It will suite your requirement. It offers lots of stuff customizing the installation process, customizing the UI, etc; [Install Anywhere](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installanywhere.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [izpack](http://izpack.org/) which multiplatform and is free (at least as beer).

Answer (score 0):

You can package your app as a JAR if it's a Java app that runs from main, a WAR if it's a web app deployed on a servlet/JSP engine, or an EAR if it's an EJB app that runs on a Java EE app server.

All these presume that your client has a JRE, servlet/JSP engine, or Java EE app server to run the app.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the osxappbundle-maven-plugin for Mac support. You don't need a mac to use it.
http://mojo.codehaus.org/osxappbundle-maven-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Nobody mentioned [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page).

Comment: NSIS is specifically "Windows" installer.